# Properly combining 2 different files

Tags: python, xml, join

Im trying to combine two different xml files using the folloing script...

```
filenames = ['file1', 'file2']
with open('file3', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())

print 'done'
```

It works, but not in the way I want. Instead of putting the different columns into their own columns, the two files stack on top of each other like this

```
time1   time2   
1   2   
1   3   
2   3   
2   4   
speed   date    number
4   1   1
4   1   2
8   1   3
8   1   4
```

...but I want it like this...

```
speed   date    number  time1   time2
4   1   1   1   2       1       2
4   1   2   1   3       1       3
8   1   3   2   3       2       3
8   1   4   2   4       2       4
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably use the builtin csv module

```
list1 = map(list,csv.reader(open("text1")))
list2 = map(list,csv.reader(open("text2")))

with open("combined.txt","wb") as f:
    csv.writer(f).write_rows(zip(*(zip(*list1)+zip(*list2))))
```

but you can do it without

```
list1 = map(str.split,open("text1"))
list2 = map(str.split,open("text2"))
with open("combined.txt","wb") as f:
     f.write("\n".join(map(" ".join,row) for row in zip(*(zip(*list1)+zip(*list2)))))
```

(I think I got enough matching parenthesis there)

or even simpler

```
with open("file3.txt","wb") as f:
    for row1,row2 in zip(open("file1"),open("file2")):
        f.write("%s\t%s\n"%(row1.strip(),row2.strip()))
```

Comment: unfortunately, all three of these aren't working, the first two have attribute and typing errors and the last one combines the first two columns of each file... any other suggestions?

Comment: It almost does! now the only thing is that the added column is added to the last column of the other... for example what should be two columns of "utm.y" and "haversine_distance" are instread one column of "utm.y haversine_distance"